# AS3 - Functions in Arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function

I've recently started using AS3, and I've ran into a little problem.

I want to store some functions into an array like so:

```
testArray:Array = [testfunction(), testfunction2()];
```

But when I start it up, all the functions will fire off without being called. Is there a way to prevent this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`()` is used to call a function, you just need to store a reference to the function. Your code calls the functions and stores their results in the array or undefined if the functions don't return anything. Try :

```
var testArray:Array = [testfunction, testfunction2];
```

To call the first function :

```
testArray[0]();
```

or :

```
var func:Function = testArray[0];
func();
```